Is it ethical for a Master's student to have someone else do their research with the intention of submitting it as their work?
A student is enrolled in an online Master's program and has asked a co-worker/ technician to develop and perforem the laboratory assay that will the be submitted upon completion to satisfy the requirements for the degree. I duagree but others do not seem to be concerned.

It's normal to work with others in science. It's rare that a submitted work, even a thesis, is actually entirely the work of one individual in an empirical field.
If the plan is to not acknowledge/disclose the source of the work, that's unethical.
If this is the entirety of the thesis, then disclosure that someone else did the work would likely prevent graduation.
It's difficult to know what exactly is going wrong (or not) in this situation without more information. If you're a third party, you may not have enough information to know.
